# custom hook in stack blitz using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, stackblitz

I am trying to learn custom hook by following the below tutorial in w3schools but I am getting the below error in stackblitz.
Can you let me know how to fix it. Providing the code and fiddle below. I googled but still no luck.

> `Error in /~/src/useFetch.js (3:18)
> Module undefined not declared as a System.registerDynamic dependency of [https://react-6tdyn9.stackblitz.io/~/src/useFetch.js](https://react-6tdyn9.stackblitz.io/%7E/src/useFetch.js)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6tdyn9?file=src%2Findex.js,src%2FuseFetch.js,src%2FApp.js

https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_customhooks.asp

```
mport { useState,useEffect } from react;

const useFetch = () => {

  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect (() =>{
    fetch(url)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => setData(data));

  }, [url]);

  return [data];

};

export default useFetch;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues in your code. Firstly the import React statment should be in string.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"; // Like this
```

Next, you are missing the url paramter in your hook. You seem to have passed it on the `useEffect` by mistake.

```
const useFetch = (url) => {  // ==> Add Url Parameter here

  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect (() =>{
    fetch(url)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => setData(data));

  }, [url]);

  return [data];

};
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, can you let me know how did you find this error  ---> mport React statment should be in string

Comment: You can try to understand the error message as it mentions the issue.  The error message said module undefined which means there is something wrong with the import statement which is importing the modules. So my first though was to check what was being imported. This is where i saw the issue. If you are familiar with how react, works you should be able to identify the issues.